# @Value Injection in Spring Boot 2.0.0 injects null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

So. After reading the official docs and finding nothing wrong with what I am doing, I just ran out of ideas.

My application.properties:

```
vz.info.version=0.2.8
```

My properties Component

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class VZProperties {

  @Value("${vz.info.version}")
  @Getter
  @Setter
  private String apiVersion;

}
```

I am getting null all over the place for the `apiVersion`.
And Lombok does not seem to be the issue. What did I miss from the docs?

**EDIT**

I would like to call it like this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import lombok.Getter;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

public class VZNFCTagResponse implements Serializable{

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -2824767225275894898L;

  @Autowired
  private VZProperties properties;

  public VZNFCTagResponse(List<VZNFCTagAction> tagList){
    this.tags = tagList;
  }

  /*...*/

  @JsonProperty
  public String apiVersion(){
    return this.properties.getApiVersion();
  }      
}
```

And after having checked to get it running via injecting Environment, the property isn't there, either.

Comment: double check, it works fine with me, i'm using `2.0.0.RELEASE` can you show us how you call this properties please?

Comment: You don't have a `new VZProperties()` some where in your code?

Comment: Judging from the name of the class you are using this in an `@Controller` and are doing `return new VZNFCTagResponse()`. Spring will only inject dependencies into spring managed beans.

Comment: @M.Deinum I got that, but I really do not want this to be a Component. Using `Environment` also does not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class VZNFCTagResponse is not registered as Spring Beans.
Annotate it as @Component and use DI for inject him.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to avoid making it into a component and still benefit from DI is to mark it `@Configurable` and enable load-time weaving. Can't you just inject it into the component that creates `VZNFCTagResponse` and pass the version as a constructor parameter?